# Find the range of $f(x)=\cos({(\pi/6)\sin[(\pi/2)(\sin x)]})$

Tags: functions

Find the range of $f(x)=\cos({(\pi/6)\sin[(\pi/2)(\sin x)]})$.

**My attempt:**

Since $-1\le\sin x\le1$, I've multiplied $\pi/2$ to the above inequality and went on multiplying till I got $(-\pi/6)\le(\pi/6)\sin[(\pi/2)(sinx)]\le\pi/6$.
The expression from $\pi$/6 is a part of cos function.

Comment: Is $f(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{6\sin(\frac{\pi}{2\sin(x)})})$?

Comment: Please format or use parentheses to make it legible

Comment: By not nesting brackets, but putting them next to each other instead, you mean multiplication? I.e. by $cos(\pi/6)((sin((\pi/2)(sinx)))$ you mean $cos(\pi/6)$ multiplied by $((sin((\pi/2)(sinx)))$, which actually is $sin((\pi/2)$ multiplied by $sinx$? I suppose not, especially that one of these above is missing closing bracket. Can you check all the brackets again? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{6}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Then, $-1\leq \sin(x) \leq 1$ implies
$$-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\leq f(x) \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry previously I did that in a hurry.
Consider the inner most parenthesis.As such varies from [-1,1],therefore the variable in second ur pi/2*sinx varies from (-Infinity,+infinity).
SO when considering the second son function,you have inputs from (-Infinity,+infinity),which gives range of [-1,1].
Now consider the cor function since the iput over here varies from [-pi/6,+pi/6],So the range of this is [(3^1/2)/2,1].

Comment: No the answer is [(root3)/2,1]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, I assume you mean $\sin x$ and $\cos x$?